# UIScrollView in middle in of page?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I am developing a UI for my application and need some content in `UIScrollView` in the middle of the page. I have a `UIView` (a) set in the main view. Something like this

[image]

I have another UIView in the same xib with uiscrollview in that UIView(b) like:

[image]

Now when I set the following:

```
[a addSubview:b];
```

the `UIView` a does something like:

[image]

Please help me out with this.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's the problem?

Comment: you see I have two uibuttons just for test right? I want the UIview to scroll not show me the uibutton until I scroll in uiview a? Does it make a lot more sense now?

Comment: No, it does not make more sense now, it is hard to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to scroll to your second button, you need to set your scroll view's contentSize in code. Take a look at the answer to this question: [How I auto size a UIScrollView to fit the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944294/how-i-auto-size-a-uiscrollview-to-fit-the-content)

Comment: The scrollview is big enough...the uibutton is like on 220 while size of scrollview is 250..i dont want to see the uibutton down there i want to scroll to it...also keep in mind that uiscrollview is in view b which is 200

Comment: A couple of points. Your scrollview's contentSize must be set to be bigger than your scrollview bounds. If you don't want to see the button, you have to clip the subviews of your scrollview. Look for the "Clip Subviews" checkbox on your scrollview in Interface Builder. Make sure that is checked and you won't see the button until you scroll to it (assuming your contentSize is set correctly).

Comment: thanks matt..had always wondered what clip to subview was for