# only scroll half content UIScrollView Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

in my app, I would apply Scrollview which there are textfields and labels.

but I was very confused, because some textfield can not be shown on the 
scroll view and the textfield "country" and further textfield not selectable. scrol bar on scrolview Nor can slide all the way down, only half of the frame content view.
how so I can scroll through the entire content and can use existing textfield?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7nrn.png)

Comment: can you please post some code or upload the project?

Comment: i don't know where is the code, cause i use storyboard

Comment: Open ViewController.swift and make an outlet with your scrollview... then on scrollViewDidLoad use my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple subviews, you need to [update the scroll view content size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944294/how-i-auto-size-a-uiscrollview-to-fit-the-content)

I you use autolayout, you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/).

Comment: no but here is a tutorial for autolayout http://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Comment: thanks that's work, but i don't understand when i use scroll layout on the constraint storyboard of scrollview must "AG" if not, the scrollview always doesn't work

Comment: i follow that tutorial, first time that work, but when i adding some textfield on the bottom screen the scroll doesn't work