# Fit UIScrollView to the content

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've too much space below content in scroll view.

Please refer to the screenshot below. How do I fit scroll view to the content. The problem seems to be the bottom space. If I just leave it as per auto layout it gets too much space below the content.

If I set it to 8 it works but storyboard complains for constraints, see screenshot no. 2 below. If this can be fixed then I'll have solution.

I've seen some suggestions (e.g. [How do I auto size a UIScrollView to fit the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944294/how-do-i-auto-size-a-uiscrollview-to-fit-the-content)) on other posts but they don't solve the issue. How to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you mean `UILabel` by `Content Text View` then ignore BTW part of my answer and don't set  any height just `.lines = 0`

Comment: There is no label, it's UITextView. Content Text View in the storyboard is UITextView.

Comment: then btw is for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed constraints:

> - ScrollView : top , leading , trailing , bottom
> - contentView : top , leading , trailing , bottom => to superView && equal width to main outer view
> - textView : top , leading , trailing , bottom => to contentView , height ( such as 50 )

BTW you don't need all of this as the `UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollview`, so it's scrollable by default.
If you need to resize it according to written text, then use:

```
self.textView.frame.size = self.textView.contentSize
```

Comment: When you say "BTW you don't need all of this as the UITextView inh.." do you mean I don't need to set any constraints?

Comment: i mean you don't need the scrollview , just drag the UItextView directly

Comment: I see yes you are right, didn't realise this simple thing.

Comment: Perfect solution as I applied it to my other VC where I had many views inside content view and it worked. I followed some other tut and I was doing it all wrong. I was giving contentView equal height as well and textView bottom was pinned to scroll view rather than contentView. Tx again you saved a lot of my time.